# Maximization with an objective function that includes a binary component

Tags: optimization, binary

I am an economist with some math background but not strong enough to solve this. I'm trying to solve:

\begin{align}
\max_x\ f(x,y(x))=a\cdot y(x)+b\cdot g(x)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
y(x)=1(h(x)>0).
\end{align}
$h(x)$ is a linear function of $x$ and $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$ are constants.  $x\in X$ and $X$ is a compact and continuous subset of $[0,1]$. $g(x)$ is a concave and differentiable function.

Now, my problem is that the optimal choice of $x$ depends on the value of $y(x)$, which depends on $x$.

I would like to know how to solve for, if possible, a closed-form solution. If it is impossible, what kind of algorithm should I use, and where can I find the essential readings to learn them.

EDIT: Thanks Robert for his great answer. Now I would just like to ask this follow-up question:

Can this method of solving for the maximum be adopted in a dynamic programming version of this problem? Say I want to maximise $V(x_t)=\max_{x_t} f(x_t,y_t(x_t))+\delta V(x_{t+1})$ but the constant $a$ now becomes a function of $x_{t−1}$? $\delta$ is a discount factor.

Comment: If $a>0$ then you should only care about maximizing f in the subset of $X$ where $h(x)>0$. If $a<0$ you should only care about maximizing f in the subset of $X$ where $h(x)<=0$. It is easy to find where $h(x)>0$ since $h$ is linear. And if $a=0$ then you can ignore $y(x)$. Correct me if I said or understood something wrong

Comment: @michailvazaios You are wrong.  Let's suppose $a > 0$.  It could be that the maximum of $b g$ in the region where $h  \le 0$ is more than $a + $ the maximum in the region where $h > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially there are two separate problems to consider:

1. maximize $b g(x)$ on $\{x: h(x) \le 0\}$.
2. maximize $a + b g(x)$ on $\{x: h(x) > 0\}$.

and then you take whichever of these solutions has the best objective value.
To complicate matters, however, there is no guarantee that a maximum is attained in (2), as $\{x: h(x) > 0\}$ is not closed.  If $a > 0$ and the maximum of $a + b g(x)$ on $\{x: h(x) \ge 0\}$ occurs only at a point where $h(x) = 0$, the problem does not have an optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer Robert. I'm not too worried about whether a maximum exists because, as I said, I am an economist, and we have a lot of (admittedly dodgy) tricks in constructing our models to make sure things work in the way we want. Just one more question to ask. Can this method of solving for the maximum be adopted in a dynamic programming version of this problem? Say I want to maximise $V(x_t)=\max_{x_t} f(x_t,y_t(x_t))+\delta V(x_{t+1})$ but the constant $a$ now becomes a function of $x_{t-1}$? $\delta$ is a discount factor.